# This code are theoretically there will be a double free, but why no repetition

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

new Widget by two smart Pointer manager，so there will be a double free of problems, but does not appear after execution

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> processedWidget;
class Widget {
 public:
  void process();
};
void Widget::process()  {
  processedWidget.emplace_back(this); 
}
int main() {
 {
   std::shared_ptr<Widget> w(new Widget);
   w->process();
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double delete is undefined behavior by the standard. So it *may appear* to work, while hiding a disaster. The correct approach for code like this is to use [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>> processedWidget;

class Widget : private std::enable_shared_from_this<Widget> {
 public:
  void process();
};

void Widget::process()  {
  processedWidget.emplace_back(shared_from_this()); 
}

int main() {
 {
   std::shared_ptr<Widget> w(new Widget);
   w->process();
 }
  return 0;
}
```